# Studio Bot Missing in latest andriod studio bot

Tags: android-studio, bots, artificial-intelligence, code-completion

I have just installed latest version of andriod studio lguana. But it is missing the studio Bot an AI code companion. I have searched a lot but unable to find it. [Preview of lguana more tools expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCYK0.png)

I want to know why studio bot is missing?

Answer (score 0):

step1: make sure you check data sharing option
File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data sharing

step2: toggle Studio Bot view section
View > Tool Windows > Studio Bot

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting helps you to improve the appearance of your post. Consider taking the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

- Agree to send data to Google so we can better understand how
  effective Studio Bot is.
- Give permission to share data either when you first install Android
  Studio or later at

  `File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data Sharing  (Android Studio > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Data Sharing on macOS)`
- To launch Studio Bot, open or start an Android Studio project and
  click

  `View > Tool Windows > Studio Bot`
- Sign in to your Google account when asked, if you aren't already
  signed in.
- The chat box appears and you can start using Studio Bot's
  interactive, conversational interface.